# letting css3 animation play through even when hover off?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css

I have a small menu logo wiggle on my site when you hover over it. it looks really good but ideally id love to make the animation play all the way through first. this is what im using:

http://daneden.me/animate/

heres my code:

js

```
$(function() {
    $('.logo').hover(function(){$(this).addClass('animated swing')},function(){$(this).removeClass('animated swing')});
});
```

css3

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
       -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
         -o-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
       -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
         -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes swing {
    20% { -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); }  
    40% { -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }   
    80% { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }  
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes swing {
    20% { -ms-transform: rotate(15deg); }   
    40% { -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes swing {
    20% { -o-transform: rotate(15deg); }    
    40% { -o-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -o-transform: rotate(5deg); } 
    80% { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg); }    
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes swing {
    20% { transform: rotate(15deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.swing {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
    -o-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
    -webkit-animation-name: swing;
    -moz-animation-name: swing;
    -ms-animation-name: swing;
    -o-animation-name: swing;
    animation-name: swing;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how long the animation takes, you could do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.logo').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated swing');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated swing');
        }, ...);
    });
});
```